# Allowing someone to reply to an email sent from a site with a php contact form

Tags: php, forms, email

I have created a php contact form to allow someone to contact a company from a form on their website.

The code works fine and the email sends without a problem. The only problem is that when the email is sent and the company wish to replay to it, it sends to a strange email rather than to the email that the user entered within the contact form. Is there any way round this?

Here is the php code for the contact form.

```html
<?php
  if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    

    $from = 'site user'; 
    $to = 'example@example.com'; 
    $subject = 'Message from a site user';
    
    $body ="From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
 
    if (!$_POST['name']) {
      $errorName = 'Please enter your name';
    }
    
    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $errorEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }
    
    
    if (!$_POST['message']) {
      $errorMessage = 'Please enter your message';
    }
    
if (!$errorName && !$errorEmail && !$errorMessage) {
  if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
    $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
  } else {
    $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later.</div>';
  }
}
  }
?>
```

Comment: [You have to add a "Reply to" in your email headers.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: sadly this didn't fix the problem

Comment: actually I did google it and already tried that but it didn't work, there is no need at all to be rude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Reply To` in your header,

Instead of passing $from as it is, do something like:

```
$from= 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Comment: sadly this also didn't fix the problem

Comment: When you hit reply, who is your email trying to reply?

Comment: it goes to example@p3plcpml0853.prod.phx3.secureserver.net

Comment: actually it's working now, I think my emails were being funny, thanks for your help.